How to get the Sharepoint list items and display in to outlook Addin using API call?
Using JavaScript I'm  developing a Addin for Outlook ,In that add-in I want dropdown with dynamic SharePoint list items, In this scenario I tried Api call but Api is not working ,As per my knowledge that Api code path is Skipped ,Anyone help me for this.
